# set admin and front in codeignitier

Tags: codeigniter

I have codeigniter 3.1.6 I am trying to separate admin and front both are in the different folder in application folder
e.g
application/admin (In this all folder and file which is in the application)
application/front (In this all folder and file which is in the application)

and localhost/ci/ load the front and localhost/ci/admin load the admin

how it is possible ? also css and js not load which is

application/admin/assets/css/ ( I used base_url(assets/css/cssfile.css) )
 same as for fron

please help I spen lot of time to set this one
this is my .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /codeigniter/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /codeigniter/index.php
</IfModule>
```

config.php

```
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = '';
/* variable */
$config['chemin_images']    = '/homepages/42/d422273845/htdocs/sites/markoub2/assets/images/';  
$config['chemin_cars']    = '/homepages/42/d422273845/htdocs/sites/markoub2/assets/images/cars/';  

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

index.php

```
<?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

As i said the webapp works fine on the Server

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Thanks but it not which I want in my case admin and front share different route file

Comment: Hmm. I can tell you what I did. In application controllers I have all my front-end files directly there and then in a subfolder I have my admin controllers. Doesn't require any routing. A bit of a pain that you constantly have to do /admin/this/that in links instead of /this/that. Then I have two core controllers one public and one admin. My front-end extends public and my backend extends admin. I did it this way because I couldn't find any other way to do it without defining a bunch of routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this below link sample boilerplate from github. You can see both frontend and admin panel as you asked.

https://github.com/jiji262/codeigniter_boilerplate

This will be helpful.

Comment: ohh thanks but still something missing in this.
i.e
I want 
1) application/admin ( copy of all file and folders of application)
2) application/front ( copy of all file and folders of application)
Hope its make sens